# How can I add the values in my object without nesting Object.entries?

Tags: javascript, json, object

My JSON looks something like this:

```json
const json = {
  "08/23/2022": {
    "One": 254,
    "Two": 92,
    "Three": 8
  },
  "08/13/2022": {
    "One": 327,
    "Two": 86,
  },
  "08/14/2022": {
    "One": 431
  },
}
```

I need to add all of these values, regardless of what the key is. In this case, the calculation would be 254+92+8+327+86+431, and the output would be 1198. Previously I had just been counting the first ([0]) value but I just realized that's not correct and the only solution I can think of is essentially nesting loops, but that doesn't seem like the cleanest or most efficient way to accomplish this. This is my current code for reference:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(json)) {
  Object.entries(value).forEach(val => output += val[1])
}
```

So what's the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fundamentally two dimensions to go through - the date-object pairs of the top level object, and then the digit-number pairs of the inner objects. So there really isn't any decent way around logic that accounts for two levels of nesting.

But, a better approach would be to use `Object.values` - you don't care about the keys, only the values.

```js
const json = {
  "08/23/2022": {
    "One": 254,
    "Two": 92,
    "Three": 8
  },
  "08/13/2022": {
    "One": 327,
    "Two": 86,
  },
  "08/14/2022": {
    "One": 431
  },
};
const sum = Object.values(json)
  .flatMap(Object.values)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

The result is 1198 because that's the result of  254+92+8+327+86+431.

Well, I suppose there's a way around using an Object or object iteration method twice (or more) - `JSON.stringify` will iterate over all nested properties anywhere - but that's silly and shouldn't be used in real code.

```js
const json = {
  "08/23/2022": {
    "One": 254,
    "Two": 92,
    "Three": 8
  },
  "08/13/2022": {
    "One": 327,
    "Two": 86,
  },
  "08/14/2022": {
    "One": 431
  },
};
let sum = 0;;
JSON.stringify(json, (_, val) => {
  if (typeof val === 'number') sum += val;
  return val;
});
console.log(sum);
```